# How to recover nodejs service from MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have build node js backend service using **mongoose(v 5.6.9)**. Service is connected to **Mongo Atlas DB(Version 4.2.6**). Service is deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The service is working fine for a couple of weeks.
But then I am getting "MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed". After that I do any DB operation then it errors with "MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms".

Below the option, I have used for mongoose connect. My connection URL looks like mongodb+srv://...

```
await mongoose.connect(URL, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
```

Is there any way that I should use and prevent this error or recover from this situation?
Also, I am not sure how to reproduce this error.

[image]